# Adding the 'active' class to the main tab list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the active class to all the main category block in my html code as follows:-

```
<ul class="tabs">

   <li class="accordion"><a href="#tab1">Boo1</a>

           <ul id="sub-nav">
              <li><a href="http://www.myweb.com"> Ipsum Text</a></li>
              <li><a> Lorem text</a></li>
              <li><a> More lorem text </a></li>
              <li><a> Dolor Sit Amet </a></li>
           </ul>                                   

  </li> 


  <li><a href="#tab2">Boo2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Boo3</a></li>
  <li class="last-item"><a href="#tab4">Boo4</a></li>

</ul>​
```

styled this way:-

```
#sub-nav  > .active {background:#AAA;}
.tabs li a.active { background: green; }
.tabs li a {font-size:20px;}
#sub-nav li a {font-size:16px; margin-left:20px;}
```

​

so I did this:-

```
(function(){
    $('.tabs #sub-nav li').bind('click', function(e){
        var subNavList   = $(this),
            list = $('.tabs').find('li').add('.tabs a');
            list.removeClass('active');  


        subNavList.addClass('active').parents('li').addClass('active').children('a').addClass('active');
    });
}());​
```

my only problem now is when the other nav list is clicked (boo2 and boo3), the active class is not applied. Please check the jsfiddle code to understand better. http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/6/  What am I doing wrong guys? Can some please help me out?

Comment: well the click is not being attached to those elements. `'.tabs #sub-nav li'`

Comment: @epascarello dear me! I don't know what was wrong with me. I have another problem though. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/8/. How do I exclude the subnavs of the boo1 from having the green color but rather have it's default ash color when the boo1 is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for (select the top nav when clicked also select both the subnav and it's parent when clicked):

http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/9/

```
(function(){

    $('.tabs a').on('click', function(e){
        $('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').children('a').addClass('active');
    })       

}());​
```

Comment: not really :( I want the Boo1 to be activated only when the sublist (Ipsum Text etc) is clicked just like my original example. What I want changed is the color of the sublist. And again, all the main list will have a background of green but the sublist is styled with the color: #aaa;

Comment: just change your css from `#sub-nav > .active {background:#AAA;}` to `#sub-nav .active {background:#AAA;}`. http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/10/

Comment: yep! my bad I basically opened a wrong fiddle! Thank you very much @scottm. the fun thing is your code is concise too :)

Comment: please checkout this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/15/ why can't I select the "a" elements of the sub navs? I want to select the li of the main elements and the "a" for the subs elements  :(